# Installing ubuntu 13.10 64 bit with windows 8.1 32 bit?

Tags: installation, 13.10

I have windows 8.1 pro 32bit installed in my laptop. 
My question is can I install ubuntu 13.10 64bit alongside windows 8.1 pro which is a 32bit OS. I don't know whether a 32 bit OS and a 64 bit OS can be installed alongside. Or should I have to go with 32 bit?

Comment: Go with 64 bit Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer is a 32-bit computer it's perfectly fine. Ubuntu will run just fine along with windows 8.

Comment: Do you mean if my computer is a 64-bit computer?

Answer (score -1):

you can do it... without any problem, but ur computer processor should 64-bit..

Comment: mine shows as x64 based processor